# mpf_set_str assign 0 from non-zero string (GMP)

Tags: c, string, gmp

I apologize in advance if there is already an answer for it.

```
mpf_t f;
mpf_init2(f, 64);
printf("input %d\n", mpf_set_str(f, "0.0415373652931074065807663354", 10));
gmp_printf ("fixed point mpf %lf\n", f);
```

The code above create prints out this:

```
input 0
fixed point mpf 0.000000
```

mpf_set_str returns 0 so it is successful. But why does it assign 0 to variable f when the input string is clearly not 0? I tried different things such as using a string variable, etc.

Other function such as

```
mpf_set_d(f, 0.0415373652931074065807663354)
```

works fine, but a lot of precision is lot with this assignment.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that you should use `%Ff` format specifier within your `gmp_printf` instead of `%lf` (or `%Lf`). For example if you want twenty decimal places, then use:

```
gmp_printf("fixed point mpf %.20Ff\n", f);
```

See [GMP documentation](https://gmplib.org/manual/Formatted-Output-Strings.html#Formatted-Output-Strings) for more reference.

The reason for this is that your `f` variable actually has `mpf_t` type, which is different that basic `double` or `long double` types, so it required special format specifier (besides that you call `gmp_printf` instead of ordinary`printf`).